# Multiple sub-string matches using process substitution

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I want to do sub-string match within .sh file and extract list of cmds and append it an existing file.

So far I'm using `perl -ne` and it works with last-matched value shown on screen as

```
echo 'declare -a org_val=($(chkconfig --list autofs) $(grep "^PROMPT="/etc/sysconfig/init)' |
    perl -pe 's|.*\$\((.*?)\)\s+|\1|g'
```

The following is the output of above command:

```
grep `"^PROMPT=" /etc/sysconfig/init`
```

I also want it to output

```
chkconfig --list autofs
```

What I did was write a small .sh to and save results of sed in array using command substitution below

```
#!/bin/bash
nl='\n'
declare -a array0
while IFS=$nl read  -r line
do
array0+=$line
#echo $line
done < <( perl -pe 's|.*\$\((.*?)\)\s+|\1|g')  < /tmp/sunny
echo "${array0[@]}"
```

The **output** of above is

```
declare -a org_val=($(chkconfig --list autofs) $(grep "^PROMPT=" /etc/sysconfig/init)
```

content of `/tmp/sunny` is

```
declare -a org_val=($(chkconfig --list autofs) $(grep "^PROMPT=" /etc/sysconfig/init) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -nle'print for /\$\(([^)]*)\)/g'
```

Of course, that assumes that no `)` exists within `$(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ echo 'declare -a org_val=($(chkconfig --list autofs) $(grep "^PROMPT="/etc/sysconfig/init)' |
awk -v RS='[$][(][^()]+' 'RT{print substr(RT,3)}'
chkconfig --list autofs
grep "^PROMPT="/etc/sysconfig/init
```